# How to check if element have any text

Tags: jquery, if-statement, text

How can I check, if element does have any text? I have found some code, but it does not work. I need to do something like this: If element has text, write this, if not, write something else.

```
    if (!$('.flexslider .item:first p').text().trim().length) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $('.text-anim-sphone').html(text);
    }
    else {
        $('.text-anim-sphone').html('welcome');
    }
```

Comment: try this: $(this).html(). For retrieving text inside an html tag, we generally use html.

Comment: Remove ! from if condition, then it should work according to your need.

Comment: @AppleBud No, we use `.text()` if we want just the text, we use `.html()` if we want all the HTML codes as well.

Comment: can you show me your fiddle?

Comment: As `Anoop Joshi` pointed out, your are checking for "no text" (length = 0) then trying to use the text!!! Get rid of the `!`

Comment: Before asking check in debugger if your code is really executed. The problem is not relevant to text() but to wrong if condition.

Comment: There is my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry3Lv/) I have also removed ! but it does not work. How do I have to change the condition? I didnt get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are checking if an element has text in and then trying to append `$(this).text()` but you have no context for `$(this)`

Try

```
var text = $('.flexslider .item:first p').text().trim();
if (text.length) {
    $('.text-anim-sphone').html(text);
} else {
    $('.text-anim-sphone').html('welcome');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `!` not check in the if, Try this:

```
if ($('.flexslider .item:first p').text().trim().length) {
    $('.text-anim-sphone').html('welcome');
} else {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('.text-anim-sphone').html(text);
}
```

---

if `0` then js evaluates it as a `false` and if any length other than `0` evaluated to `true`.